# Worst case bisection of binary tree

Tags: binary-trees

My algorithm book states that any n-vertex binary tree T can be partitioned by just removing a single edge into two disconnected trees A and B where neither of them has more than 3/4 of the vertices.

It sounds like it should be simple to create such a tree, but I can't imagine one, my bisections are always better balanced. Can somebody show me a tree where the vertex distribution of 3/4 to 1/4?

This is from "Introduction to Algorithms" by Thomas Cormen, 3rd edition, MIT Press. Appendix B, Problems B-3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a simple binary tree $T$ with only 4 nodes: The root of $T$ is $A$. $A$ has a left child $B$ which has two children $C$ and $D$.

Comment: Ouch. Yes, so simple that I didn't get it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody said that $3/4$ was the optimal number. In fact, it seems like $2/3$ might be achievable. Starting at the root, consider a walk which always chooses the child with the larger subtree. Consider the first time that you reach a node whose subtree contains less than $2/3$ of the nodes. Its parent's subtree contains more than $2/3$ of the nodes, so the subtree rooted at its larger child contains at least $1/3$ of the nodes. So we have found a node whose subtree contains between $1/3$ and $2/3$ of the nodes.

Considering the tree with one root and two children, we see that we can't in general obtain a better balanced partition.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed what it seems to me, too. But the book (which has a quite good reputation) states, that the worst case for any tree graph is 3/4. I'd like to understand that. I tried to find a graph which does not allow a better balanced bisection than 3/4 to 1/4 with removal of 1 edge, but I failed. In the worst case I end up with 2/3, too.
So, is the book wrong?

Comment: Perhaps. Nobody's perfect. It could also be that my proof sketch doesn't work. Fortunately, there is a remedy. You can check to see whether my proof works. If it does, then 3/4 can be lowered to 2/3. Otherwise, you will probably get a counterexample to 2/3, in which the best constant will probably be 3/4.

Comment: I think the little flaw of your argument lies in the "rounding" of rational numbers to integers. (Consider a simple binary tree $T$ with only 4 nodes: The root of $T$ is $A$. $A$ has a left child $B$ which has two children $C$ and $D$.)